# GREP: Change spaces for tabs in specific conditions

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep, character-styles, editorial-design

I want to know the way in InDesign with GREPs, if possible, to any paragraph that starts with numbers followed by a period and a space ("00" + [.] + [space]"), and replace the space for a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what:

```
^(\d+\.)\s
```

Change to:

```
$1,
```

[image]